# What is the best solution for adding INDEX to speed up the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Now I have a Query that runs 50 minutes on Mysql database and I can't accept that...

I want this process can running under 15 minutes....

```
insert into appianData.IC_DeletedRecords 
            (sourcetableid, 
             concatkey, 
             sourcetablecode) 
select mstid, 
        concatkey, 
        'icmstlocationheader' as sourcetablecode 
 from   appianData.IC_MST_LocationHeader
 where  concatkey not in(select concatkey 
                         from appianData.IC_PURGE_LocationHeader)
```

The "sourcetableid" and "mstid" are unique.

So what is the best way to add INDEX or optimize on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the `select` as:

```
select mstid, concatkey,  'icmstlocationheader' as sourcetablecode 
from  appianData.IC_MST_LocationHeader lh
where not exists (select 1 
                  from appianData.IC_PURGE_LocationHeader lhp
                  where lhp.concatkey = lh.concatkey
                 );
```

Then you want an index on `IC_PURGE_LocationHeader(concatkey)`.

Comment: Much to my surprise, `NOT IN` beat `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN` in a sample test on MySQL 5.5 thru 8.0.  (I need to find some more tests.)

Comment: @RickJames . . . That surprises me too.  I assume you have the specified index.

Comment: They all say "Using index"; I think it is a valid test.  Timings were 11ms to 27ms across  9 versions.  Lots of different EXPLAINs.  Tentative conclusions:  Use NOT EXISTS on MariaDB 10; use NOT IN for on MySQL/Percona.  (5K rows in base table; resultset was 10% of that.)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a `NOT IN` condition you should be able to use a "LEFT JOIN ... WHERE rightTable has no match" without concern for multiple matches inflating the results.

```
INSERT INTO appianData.IC_DeletedRecords (sourcetableid, concatkey, sourcetablecode) 
SELECT m.mstid, m.concatkey, 'icmstlocationheader' as sourcetablecode 
FROM appianData.IC_MST_LocationHeader AS m
LEFT JOIN appianData.IC_PURGE_LocationHeader AS p
   ON m.concatkey = p.concatkey
WHERE p.concatkey IS NULL
;
```

With this version query, or the one you presented in the question, indexes on `concatkey` in both source tables should help significantly.

Comment: Only the index on `p` will be used.  Your query will scan all of `m`, reaching into `p` to see if it is missing.  That needs `p: INDEX(concatkey)`.